# Custom distribution is always giving the same value in Anylogic

Tags: java, random, anylogic

I am using AnyLogic for a simulation, and in a function I made, I am creating a custom distribution from a list of observations (integers) which I stored in a database table (some values are `10,12,10,14,16,20,21,23,11,...`).

The problem is that after creating the custom distribution programatically, it returns always the same value from the distribution (`14`). I thought that fixing the seed at 0 was causing the problem, so I wrote this code to compute a random seed for each execution and use it to get the random value from the custom distribution :

```
CustomDistribution dist = new CustomDistribution(leadtimes);
int seed = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 100 + 1);
traceln("Seed : "+seed);
delay = dist.get(new Random(seed));
```

In this code, `leadtimes` is a list of integer observations, `seed` is generated randomly each time, `dist` is the custom distribution object, and `delay` is the random value that I would like to get.

**In short :**

How to generate a random value that is different each time from a custom distribution created programatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing things exactly right, nevertheless it's likely that the seed range you chose produces all the same value...

try this, and you will see you get different values:

```
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i+=10221){
    traceln(dist.get(new Random(i)));
}
```

The seed allows you to have 1 reproducible run, but there's no control over what result this will produce, so you can have a significantly huge range of consecutive seed values that will give you the exact same result.

Comment: thank you, this was the issue indeed, I increased the range to 100 000 and it's giving different values.